# How to detect AWS ECR public repositories using Cloud Custodian?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, cloudcustodian

I'm new to Cloud Custodian and have the few doubts specific to using it for AWS.

I ran the following policy (no filters and actions present) so that I could get all the options for using as keys in value type filters :

```
    policies:
      - name: CheckPublicECRRepo
        resource: ecr
```

The output was a detailed list of all the AWS ECR **private** repositories in my account which is exactly same as running `aws ecr describe-repositories --region <region>`.

So,

1. How AWS CLI command responses relate to those from running Cloud Custodian commands? Are they both calling same APIs? If yes, which API is being called here exactly?
2. How can I write a Cloud Custodian policy to detect AWS ECR **public** repositories? I'm getting the desired output by running this AWS CLI command : `aws ecr-public describe-repositories --region us-east-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ecr-public` resource does not seem to be supported yet. So I would either submit a feature request [here](https://github.com/cloud-custodian/cloud-custodian/issues) or I would try to code the missing feature and [contribute](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/contribute.html) it.